# typedef struct with enum in main() not working

Tags: c++, struct, enums, typedef

Its practically 4 AM here, I really give up, someone help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int d;

typedef struct my_data
{

    enum calling_func
    {
        TEST_A,
        TEST_B,
        TEST_C
    } val;

}letter_data;


int main() {
    letter_data l;
    l.val = TEST_A; // error: 'TEST_A' was not declared in this scope

    cout << "test" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm getting error that TEST_A was not declared in this scope. I'm a beginner with c++ so I admit I'm stupid if not worse ...

Comment: The `struct` definition creates a new scope.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
int main() {
    letter_data l;
    l.val = my_data::TEST_A; // error: 'TEST_A' was not declared in this scope

    cout << "test" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

By the way, in C++ you don't need the `typedef`, remove it.

**Edit 1: Example without `typedef`**

```
struct letter_data
{

    enum calling_func
    {
        TEST_A,
        TEST_B,
        TEST_C
    } val;

};


int main() {
    letter_data l;
    l.val = letter_data::TEST_A; // error: 'TEST_A' was not declared in this scope

    cout << "test" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: im a beginner ... tried removing that and got error ... do you have an example perhaps ? Thank you!

Comment: See the structure declaration.  Notice that I moved the `letter_data` identifier from the end of the structure to replace the tag name of `my_data`.  I also changed the qualifier for `TEST_A` in the `main()` function.

Comment: Remember, if this answer is useful, click on the check mark.

Answer (score 2):

Clang produces a very readable error message:

```
[8:10pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] clang++ red.cc 
red.cc:21:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TEST_A'; did you mean 'my_data::TEST_A'?
    l.val = TEST_A; // error: 'TEST_A' was not declared in this scope
            ^~~~~~
            my_data::TEST_A
red.cc:11:9: note: 'my_data::TEST_A' declared here
        TEST_A,
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: hmmm what ide are you using? Using Codeblocks and it didn't really mentioned about that my_data::TEST_A :( 
also zuper thanks, that was fast  ... my morning ...